# Learning java, cannot find symbol

Tags: java, string, recursion

I'm learning Java and stuck on a self test exercise writing a recursive function that prints a string backwards...

I understand the compiler error but I'm not sure what to do about it.

My code...

```
class Back {
    void Backwards(String s) {
            if (s.length = 0) { 
                    System.out.println();
                    return;
            }
            System.out.print(s.charAt(s.length));
            s = s.substring(0, s.length-1);
            Backwards(s);
    }
}

class RTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
            Back b;
            b.Backwards("A STRING");
    }
```

}

Compiler output...

```
john@fekete:~/javadev$ javac Recur.java 
Recur.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    if (s.length = 0) { 
         ^
  symbol:   variable length
  location: variable s of type String
Recur.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.print(s.charAt(s.length));
                               ^
  symbol:   variable length
  location: variable s of type String
Recur.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    s = s.substring(0, s.length-1);
                        ^
  symbol:   variable length
  location: variable s of type String
3 errors
```

Finished code...

```
class Back {
    static void backwards(String s) {
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                    System.out.println();
                    return;
            }
            System.out.print(s.charAt(s.length()-1));
            s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
            backwards(s);
    }
}

class RTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

            Back.backwards("A STRING");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please respect tha Java naming conventions: methods start with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
s.length() == 0 // it's a method, not an attribute
```

Answer (score 2):

Some general 'good coding' suggestions:

- Class names should represent a 'thing', usually a classname is a noun (e.g. "StringTool")
- Methods should represent an action, usually a methodname is a verb (e.g. "reverse")
- Parameter and variable names should be meaningful and describe what they represent.
- You should not re-assign method parameters because it can be misleading.
- A method should have precisely one responsability (so not reversing AND printing a string). This promotes clarity and reuse.

I have applied these suggestions to your finished code, see below:

```
public class StringTool {

    public static String reverse(String source) {

        // stop condition of the recursion
        if (source.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }

        int lastPosition = source.length() - 1;
        String lastCharacter = source.charAt(lastPosition);
        String restOfSource = source.substring(0, lastPosition);

        // place the last character at the beginning and reverse the rest 
        // of the source recursively
        return lastCharacter + reverse(restOfSource);
    }

    // test method
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(reverse("A STRING"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement, you are assigning 0 to s.length rather than checking. do it this way:

```
if(s.length()==0)
//rest of your code
```

another fault is `s.charAt(s.length())`. The index of i th character in a string is (i-1), similar to the indices of an array. So the last character of the string has index `(s.length()-1)`. So replace that line of code with `s.charAt(s.length()-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

This should better reflect what you're trying to accomplish:

```
class Back {
    void Backwards(String s) {
            if (s.length() == 0) { 
                    System.out.println();
                    return;
            }
            System.out.print(s.charAt(s.length()));
            s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
            Backwards(s);
    }
}

public class RTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
            Back b = new Back();
            b.Backwards("RAPE APE");
    }
}
```

- length() is a function
- comparison uses `==`
- You must instantiate b to use it

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parentheses:

```
s.length()
```

Answer (score 0):

`length` is a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29), not an attribute. You'll have to use it that way:

```
s.length(); // note the use of parens
```

---

Also, you'll have a compilation error after fixing that, because of the following condition:

```
if (s.length = 0) {
```

It should be

```
if (s.length == 0) {
```

---

And finally, in your `main` method, the `b` variable will have to be instantiated, using

```
Back b = new Back();
```

Comment: Just answer the question, don't spoil the learning experience by fixing all the bugs for me. Besides, there were way more problems than just that.

Comment: I'm most sorry to have ruined the experience. Be assured I won't make the same mistake twice.

Answer (score 0):

**-** With `String` we are provided a **function** named `length()` and **not** a field `length`.

**-** If you were using an `Array` then it would had been `length` as **Array has one and only one Instance variable** named `length`.

**Eg:**

```
s.length() == 0;
```